# What do you call someone who has a lot of power and keeps a big secret?

Tags: word-request, nouns

I need help for a name of an essay for a school project.

What do you call someone who has a lot of power in maintaining order in a country and keeps a big secret that affects everyone but doesn't want to say it in fear he will lose his position. I need a noun.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the details, perhaps:

- A conspirator (someone conspiring in secret, often to seize or keep power)
- A fraud (someone who deceives others, perhaps about their own credentials)
- A schemer
- A plotter
- A despot (someone with absolute, unlimited power)
- An imposter (someone who ought not be in the position they are in, perhaps by pretending to be someone they are not)

Answer (score 0):

From Merriam-Webster.

[**Mastermind**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mastermind):

> : a person who supplies the directing or creative intelligence for a project
>   //  the *mastermind* behind the terrorist plot
>   //  the real *mastermind* behind the embezzlement scheme

---

However, I doubt you're going to find *any* word that also explicitly means *secret*—or that the position will be lost if the information becomes known.